# JavaScript: Sorting array accorting to "outside" parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

In JavaScript, I have an array of objects and an input value like this:

```
const inputVal = 'foo';

const objArray = [
    {title: 'blahaa', type: 'foobar'},
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'wohoo'},
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'foobar'},
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'aaaabaa'},
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'moo'},
    {title: 'aaah', type: 'foogoo'},
    {title: 'foohiii', type: 'foobar'},
    {title: 'aaah', type: 'foobar'},
    {title: 'foodoo', type: 'aaaabaa'},
    {title: 'gaaaaaah', type: 'foobar'},
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'foogoo'},
];
```

As you can see, all elements in the array have properties starting with "foo" in either the title or the type. Also, all elements are unique, the same title and/or type can be in several elements, but the same combination of both cannot appear twice.

I want to sort this array in the following way:

1. Both title and type starts with `inputVal`

   1. Type alphabetically
   2. Title alphabetically
2. Title starts with `inputVal` but not type

   1. Type alphabetically
   2. Title alphabetically
3. Type starts with `inputVal` but not title

   1. Type alphabetically
   2. Title alphabetically

The example list would be sorted as following:

```
const objArray = [
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'foobar'}, // Criterium 1
    {title: 'foohiii', type: 'foobar'}, // Criterium 1
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'foogoo'}, // Criterium 1
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'aaaabaa'}, // Criterium 2
    {title: 'foodoo', type: 'aaaabaa'}, // Criterium 2
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'moo'}, // Criterium 2
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'wohoo'}, // Criterium 2
    {title: 'aaah', type: 'foobar'}, // Criterium 3
    {title: 'blahaa', type: 'foobar'}, // Criterium 3
    {title: 'gaaaaaah', type: 'foobar'}, // Criterium 3
    {title: 'aaah', type: 'foogoo'}, // Criterium 3
];
```

I tried using `array.prototype.sort(callback)` with several different callback functions, but I don't seem to get the correct one. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What should happen if `foo` isn’t included anywhere?

Comment: please display your existing callback function

Comment: What are the different callback that you've checked?

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question. Have you tried using `startsWith`?

Comment: why is `aaah` below `gaaaaah`? in the original order both have a different order and no rule switches them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could chanin the criteria and sort by the three groups first and then by the values.

```js
const
    value = 'foo',
    start = (v => s => s.startsWith(v))(value),
    array = [{ title: 'blahaa', type: 'foobar' }, { title: 'foobar', type: 'wohoo' }, { title: 'foobar', type: 'foobar' }, { title: 'foobar', type: 'aaaabaa' }, { title: 'foobar', type: 'moo' }, { title: 'aaah', type: 'foogoo' }, { title: 'foohiii', type: 'foobar' }, { title: 'aaah', type: 'foobar' }, { title: 'foodoo', type: 'aaaabaa' }, { title: 'gaaaaaah', type: 'foobar' }, { title: 'foobar', type: 'foogoo' }];
    
array.sort((a, b) =>
       (start(b.title) && start(b.type)) - (start(a.title) && start(a.title))
    || start(b.title) - start(a.title)
    || start(b.type) - start(a.type)
    || a.type.localeCompare(b.type)
    || a.title.localeCompare(b.title)
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, probably less efficient due to the use of multiple regex.

```js
const objArray = [
    {title: 'blahaa', type: 'foobar'},
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'wohoo'},
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'foobar'},
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'aaaabaa'},
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'moo'},
    {title: 'aaah', type: 'foogoo'},
    {title: 'foohiii', type: 'foobar'},
    {title: 'aaah', type: 'foobar'},
    {title: 'foodoo', type: 'aaaabaa'},
    {title: 'gaaaaaah', type: 'foobar'},
    {title: 'foobar', type: 'foogoo'}
];

const input = "foo";

const sortedObjArray = [
    objArray.sort((a, b) => {
        const
            regex = new RegExp("^(" + input + ")?(.*)", "i"),
            titleAExec = regex.exec(a.title),
            typeAExec = regex.exec(a.type),
            titleBExec = regex.exec(b.title),
            typeBExec = regex.exec(b.type)

        const
            titleComparison = titleAExec[2].localeCompare(titleBExec[2]),
            typeComparison = typeAExec[2].localeCompare(typeBExec[2])

        if (titleAExec[1] && !titleBExec[1])
            return -1
        else if (titleBExec[1] && !titleAExec[1])
            return 1

        if (typeAExec[1] && !typeBExec[1])
            return -1
        else if (typeBExec[1] && !typeAExec[1])
            return 1

        if (typeComparison === 0)
            return titleComparison

        return typeComparison;
    })
]

console.log(sortedObjArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

1. Split array in 3 subarrays using Array.prototype.filter based on 3 Criterias as mentioned above.
2. Sort 3 subarrays independently and then concatenate using Array.prototype.concat

To improve performance, process all subarrays **asynchronously**.
Divide and Conquer wins!

Comment: Filter wouldn't work here filter removes elements, rather, sort would. You've generalised the problem and haven't provided a clear solution. Asynchronicity is unrelated to this problem. Try creating a runnable solution instead, that actually works, and backup why it would work, rather than just stating it.

Comment: By split I meant doing this -> https://jsfiddle.net/y1wL7dsq/ and now each array can be alphabetically sorted in async before doing concat.

Comment: Why don't you make a snippet here then, showing what you mean?

Comment: It worked, but you can place that code into a snippet here.

Comment: I still don't understand why my answer is downvoted. I assumed OP is already familiar with sorting alphabetically and only provided the main logic that was required.

Comment: Sure, but most people are looking for code examples. You are correct in what you have done, but if you put that code into a snippet in your answer, it would receive positive attention.

Comment: Cool. I'm new here and didn't know how much people value CTRL+C and CTRL+V. Will try putting snippets going forward.